# Как подключиться к Bitbucket после удаление локальной репозитории?

Tags: git

Когда я переносил проект с `windows` на `mac` я удалил папку `.git`.
Тепер я обратно перенес проект с `mac` на `windows`.
Как мне правильно подключить и настроить `git`, чтобы `AS` сверил `local` и `remote` базу и во время `commit` показал изменения которые произошли на `mac`? А то у меня пусто показывает.

Comment: Склонируйте репозиторий, а потом поверх скоруйте все файлы, которые вы поменяли, с перезаписыванием. Только сделайте сначала резервную копию :)

Comment: Лучше склонировать репозиторий и скопировать в проект папку `.git` из него.

Comment: @woesss спасибо, получилось...

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

В папке дайте команду `git init`. Она инициализирует новый репозиторий.

Затем добавьте ремоут командой `git remote add origin URL_вашего_репозитория`